# add table's cell content to toc

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to add to Table of Contents (toc) the content of a cell in a table? I wrote a whole chapter as a table, using 'tabularx', so it extends for several pages (more than 400 rows). So, I would like to associate particular words of certain cells to the toc.
Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textheight=24cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,newtxtext,newtxmath,multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}   
\pdfminorversion=7
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}
%
\newcommand{\hc}[1]{\hspace{#1 cm}\textquotedbl}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}
\newcommand{\np}[1]{$^\mathbf{#1}$}
%
\usepackage{multicol,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}
  {\hfill}
  {\leaders\hbox{\normalfont$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}
  \hfill}
  {}{}
%
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \begin{multicols}{2}[\section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}]%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \end{multicols}%
    }
\makeatother 
%
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=,linkcolor=blue}
%
\pagestyle{plain}
%-----[   document   ]
\begin{document}
%
\includepdf[width=\textwidth]{./mw1}
%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
%
%-----[   colors   ]
%
\definecolor{prejilla}{HTML} {cc6699}
\definecolor{pnon}    {HTML} {a0d6b4}
\definecolor{ppar}    {HTML} {ffffd7}
%
%-----[   counter  ]
%
\newcommand{\cp}[1]{%
  \rowcolor{\pparOrpnon}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \stepcounter{prowcolors}%
  \fi
  #1
}
\newcommand{\pparOrpnon}{%
  \ifodd\value{prowcolors}ppar\else pnon\fi
}
\newcounter{prowcolors}
%
\newcommand{\rp}[3]{\cp{#1} & #2 & #3}     %   renglón p
%
%-----[   toc entries   ]
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{P}
\includepdf[width=\textwidth]{mw2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Pedro a Pedro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{prudencia}
%
%-----[   tabla p   ]
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[ 1pt]}>{\bfseries\color{black}}l                   
  !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[.7pt]}>{\color{black}}l
  !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[.7pt]}>{\color{black}}X
  !{\color{prejilla}\VRule[1pt]}}          

\arrayrulecolor{prejilla}                
%
%-----[   heading   ]
%
\specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
\rowcolor{pnon}                    
 
\rp{Concepto}{\bfseries Clave}{}{\bfseries Cita}\\

\specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}
%
%-----[   table   ]
%
\rp{Pablo}          {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                       caballero\\
                       andante\\
                     \end{tabular}}        {San Pablo, caballero andante por la vida y santo a pie quedo por la
                                           muerte \np{987} (v anécdotas - San Pablo)} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pacer}          {nacer}                {<<No con quien naces, sino con quien paces>> \np{616,\ 794,\ 1066}} 
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{paciencia}      {ausencia}             {¿Y quién prueba mi paciencia?  Ausencia \np{260} (v celos)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {Dios}                 {Dios es grande: paciencia y basta \np{202}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {escarmentar}          {pero ya está hecho: paciencia, y escarmentar para desde aquí adelante 
                                           \np{211}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {injurias}             {muchas veces suele caerse la paciencia cuando la cargan de injurias
                                           \np{1003}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pacífico}       {gordo}                {hombre que, por ser muy gordo, era muy pacífico \np{38}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{padre}          {cierre ojos}          {Vive aún mi padre muriendo con el deseo de saber de su hijo mayor, y 
                                           pide a Dios con continuas oraciones no cierre la muerte sus ojos hasta que él
                                           vea con vida a los de su hijo \np{444}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {virtudes}             {Sé padre de las virtudes y padrastro de los vicios \np{942}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{padrastro}      {Cervantes}            {Pero yo, que, aunque parezco padre, soy padrastro de Don Quijote \np{7}
                                           (v péñola)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {vicios}               {Sé padre de las virtudes y padrastro de los vicios \np{942}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{padres}         {dar estado}           {no habían de dar los padres a sus hijos estado contra su voluntad
                                           \np{107}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {enojo}                {el tiempo o la muerte ha de acabar el enojo de sus padres \np{197}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {hijos}                {A los padres toca el encaminarlos desde pequeños por los pasos de la
                                           virtud, de la buena crianza y de las buenas y cristianas costumbres \np{666}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {humildes}             {De este señor son vasallos mi padres, humildes en linaje, pero tan
                                           ricos, que si los bienes de su naturaleza igualaran a los de su fortuna, ni
                                           ellos tuvieran más que desear ni yo temiera verme en la desdicha en que me
                                           veo (v Dorotea) \np{278}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {juramento}            {para el juramento que hago, que es por vida de mis padres, que los tengo
                                           vivos y los amo y los quiero mucho \np{936}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {oficio}               {bien es que los hijos hereden y aprendan los oficios de los padres
                                           \np{587}} \\ %☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{paga}           {queja}                {vale más buena queja que mala paga \np{597}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pagador}        {buen}                    {---Al buen pagador no le duelen prendas \np{647,\ 779,\ 817,\ 1000,\
                                           1085}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pagar}          {dinero}               {<<a dineros pagados, brazos quebrados>> \np{1086}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pájaro}         {comiesen}             {me levantaron en el aire para que me comiesen vencejos y otros pájaros
                                           \np{958}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {nidos}                {por no haber hallado nidos donde pensó hallar pájaros \np{657}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.3}}              {ya en los nidos de antaño no hay pájaros hogaño \np{1103}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{palabra}        {blandas}              {---Para conmigo no hay palabras blandas, que ya yo os conozco, fementida
                                           canalla --dijo don Quijote. \np{80}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {cumplir}              {y fuérzame la ley de caballería a cumplir mi palabra antes que mi gusto
                                       \np{314}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.4}}              {la experiencia le había mostrado cuán mal cumplian los libres las 
                                           palabras que daban en el cautiverio \np{417}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.4}}              {y, aunque perdí la honra, no perdí ni puedo perder la virtud de cumplir
                                           mi palabra \np{1055}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.4}}              {creo que la cumplirás, porque, en efecto, aunque tonto, eres hombre
                                           verídico.}  \\
\rp{}               {}                    {}{---No soy verde, sino moreno --dijo Sancho--, pero aunque fuera de mezcla,
                                           cumpliera mi palabra \np{857}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {loco}                 {no había para qué hacer cuenta de las palabras de un loco \np{232}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {obras}                {<<operibus credite, et non verbis>> (creed en las obras y no en las
                                           palabras) \np{750}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {Quijote}              {don Quijote hirió el aire con semejantes palabras \np{994}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.4}}              {acreditaré mis palabras cumpliendo la que di de mi promesa \np{1055} (v
                                           Quijote - derrota)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {rumiar}               {Enfrena la lengua, considera y rumia las palabras antes que te salgan de
                                           la boca \np{787}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {tratar}               {Al que has de castigar con obras no trates mal con palabras \np{870}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {villano}              {no hay villano que guarde palabra que tiene, si él ve que no le está 
                                           bien guardalla \np{318}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {vino}                 {el vino demasiado ni guarda secreto ni cumple palabra \np{872}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{palomar}        {cebo}                 {si al palomar no le falta cebo, no le faltarán palomas \np{597}} \\ %☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{palos}          {caballero}            {¿qué caballero andante ha habido, hay ni habrá en el mundo que no tenga
                                           bríos para dar él solo cuatrocientos palos a cuatrocientos cuadrilleros que
                                           se le pongan delante? \np{473}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {perro}                {todo el mal nos viene junto, como al perro los palos \np{1069}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {ventero}              {les asió al salir de la puerta, y pidió su paga y les afeó su mala
                                           intención con tales palabras, que les movió a que le respondiesen con los
                                           puños \np{461}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
       Pedro\\
       a Pedro\\
    \end{tabular}} {no iguales}           {Vuestra merced mire cómo habla, señor barbero, que no todo es hacer
                                           barbas y algo va de Pedro a Pedro \np{489}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.7}}              {y aunque todos seamos caballeros, va mucha diferencia de los unos a los
                                           otros \np{589} (v cortesano)} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pelear}         {endriago}             {peleando en las sierras de Armenia con algún endriago o con algún fiero
                                           vestiglo \np{313}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {ganas}                {---Si la mucha gana de pelear, señor caballero, no os gasta la cortesía
                                           \np{651}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{peligro}        {buscar}               {quien busca el peligro perece en él \np{176}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{peligroso}      {aventurero}           {en el otro mundo no hay estado más peligroso que el de los aventureros
                                           \np{187}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pelillos}       {pendencias}           {---Echemos, Panza amigo, pelillos a la mar en esto de nuestras
                                           pendencias \np{309}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pena}           {afrenta}              {esta afrenta es pena de mi pecado, y justo castigo del cielo es que a un
                                           caballero andante vencido le coman adivas y le piquen avispas y le hollen
                                           puercos \np{1066}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {condenar}             {no es mi pena igual a la ocasión que me condena \np{213}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {delito}               {no merece otra pena si no comete nuevo delito \np{93} (v pecado)} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{Penélope}       {Camila}               {otra nueva y perseguida Penélope \np{359}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pensamientos}   {amorosos}             {en la soledad de los campos, donde a rienda suelta podía dar vado a sus
                                           amorosos pensamientos \np{1096}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                        cosas\\
                        obscenas\\
                     \end{tabular}}        {de las cosas obscenas y torpes los pensamientos se han de apartar,
                                           cuanto más los ojos \np{1003}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {discurso}             {volveré a mejor discurso mis pensamientos \np{273}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {favorecer}            {el cielo será servido de favorecer a nuestros tan justos y tan honrados
                                           pensamientos \np{364}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {malandantes}          {todas las cosas que veía con mucha facilidad las acomodaba a sus
                                           desvariadas caballerías y malandantes pensamientos \np{189}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {morir}                {déjame morir a mí a manos de mis pensamientos y a fuerzas de mis
                                           desgracias \np{996}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {moscas}               {como moscas a la miel, le acudían y picaban pensamientos \np{1059}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {Quijote}              {Dulcinea del Toboso, única señora de mis más escondidos pensamientos 
                                           \np{143,\ 993}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.4}}              {Si muchos pensamientos fatigaban a don Quijote antes de ser derribado,
                                           muchos más le fatigaron después de caído \np{1059}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {Sancho}               {cuando no tenía otros pensamientos que los que me daban los cuidados de
                                           remendar vuestros aparejos y de sustentar vuestro corpezuelo, dichosas eran
                                           mis horas, mis días y mis años \np{956} (v SP - rucio)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {silencio}             {El silencio fue allí el que habló por los dos amantes y los ojos fueron
                                           las lenguas que descubrieron sus alegres y honestos pensamientos \np{1052}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pensar}         {excusado}             {es pensar en lo excusado \np{578,\ 597,\ 953,\ 1055}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{peñas}          {dádivas}              {dádivas quebrantan peñas \np{827}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{péñola}         {Cervantes}            {Para mí sola nació don Quijote, y yo para él: él supo obrar y yo
                                           escribir, solos los dos somos para en uno \np{1105} (v Cervantes, padrastro)}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{perder}         {bien}                 {No hemos conocido el bien hasta que le hemos perdido \np{964}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {ganar}                {que lo que hoy se pierde se gane mañana \np{70}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.3}}              {mientras se gana algo no se pierde nada \np{596}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {vida}                 {perder la vida, la mayor de las desdichas \np{262}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {\hc{.2}}              {temiendo perder la vida, que ya me cansa \np{1042}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{perdonar}       {errar}                {---¿Pensáis --le dijo a cabo de rato--, villano ruin, que ha de haber
                                           lugar siempre para ponerme la mano en la horcajadura y que todo ha de ser
                                           errar vos y perdonaros yo? \np{306}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {injurias}             {Porque aquel que dice injurias, cerca está de perdonar \np{1082}} 
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pereza}         {diligencia}           {Mas ahora ya triunfa la pereza de la diligencia \np{556} (v triunfar)}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {matar}                {Hemos de matar a la pereza, con andar por todas las partes del mundo,
                                           buscando ocasiones que nos puedan hacer y hagan sobre cristianos, famosos
                                           caballeros \np{606} (v fama)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {pecados}              {pero triunfan ahora, por pecados de las gentes, la pereza, la ociosidad,
                                           la gula y el regalo \np{684}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {ventura}              {y la pereza, contraria a la buena ventura, jamás llegó al término que
                                           píde un buen deseo \np{873}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{prolijidad}     {fastidio}             {de la prolijidad se suele engendrar el fastidio \np{753}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{promesas}       {cumplir}              {acreditaré mis palabras cumpliendo la que di de mi promesa \np{1055} (v
                                           Quijote - derrota)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {enamorados}           {le hubiera estado mejor no haber sido tan fácil en creer promesas de
                                           enamorados, las cuales por la mayor parte son ligeras de prometer y muy
                                           pesadas de cumplir \np{947}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {Sancho}               {Y estaba peor Sancho despierto que su amo durmiendo: tal le tenían las
                                           promesas que su amo le había hecho \np{368}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{prometer}       {cumplir}              {lo que una vez promete un caballero procura cumplirlo, aunque le cueste
                                           la vida \np{809}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{provecho}       {fama}                 {provecho quiero, que sin él no vale un cuatrín la buena fama \np{1033}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{providencia}    {alforjas}             {tus alforjas igualmente envidio, que mostraron tu cuerda providencia. 
                                           \np{20}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {hormigas}             {de las bestias han recibido muchos advertimientos los hombres y
                                           aprendido muchas cosas de importancia, como son, de las hormigas, la
                                           providencia \np{633} (v animales)} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{prudencia}      {amar}                 {¿Es necedad amar? No es gran prudencia \np{25}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {cargo}                {los no de principios nobles deben acompañar la gravedad del cargo que
                                           ejercitan con una blanda suavidad que, guiada por la prudencia, los libre
                                           de la mumuración maliciosa, de quien no hay estado que se escape \np{868}}
                                           \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {hacer el bien}        {sé que una de las partes de la prudencia es que lo que se puede hacer
                                           por bien no se haga por mal \np{207}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {temeridad}            {la valentía que no se funda sobre la basa de la prudencia se llama
                                           temeridad \np{767}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{prudente}       {hacienda}             {que atendiese a granjear hacienda por medios lícitos e industriosos, que
                                           nunca faltan a los prudentes y aplicados \np{715}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {guardarse}            {Cuando el valiente huye, la superchería está descubierta, y es de 
                                           varones prudentes guardarse para mejor ocasión \np{766}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {simples}              {es más el número de los simples que de los prudentes \np{493}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{prueba}         {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
                       Curioso\\
                       Impertinente\\
                     \end{tabular}}        {Anselmo, y no quieras hacer más pruebas de las hechas; sino haz de cuenta
                                           que estás ya en seguro puerto y aférrate con las áncoras de la buena
                                           consideración \np{349}} \\ %☺
\rp{}               {verdad}               {para sacar una verdad en limpio menester son muchas pruebas y repruebas
                                           \np{753}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{puente}         {plata}                {¡al enemigo que huye, hacerle puente de plata! \np{158,\ 995}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{puerta}         {abrir}                {<<Donde una puerta se cierra, otra se abre>> \np{188}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {campo}                {¿quién puede poner puertas al campo?  \np{233,\ 973}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {cerrada}              {pareciéndome que aún no estaba del todo cerrada la puerta a mi remedio
                                           \np{287}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {honra}                {y a lo que creo le debí de encerrar más de dos balas en el cuerpo,
                                           abriéndole puertas por donde envuelta en su sangre saliese mi honra
                                           \np{1010}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {sueño}                {puertas del sueño \np{1005} (v Nota 2, sueño)} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {ventura}              {---Siempre deja la ventura una puerta abierta en las desdichas para dar
                                           remedio a ellas \np{136}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pulgares}       {muelas}               {entre dos muelas cordales nunca pongas tus pulgares \np{875}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{pulgas}         {cama}                 {¡Así se me vuelvan las pulgas de la cama! \np{305}} \\ %☺ ☺
\rp{}               {matar}                {si no fuese por el valor que ella infunde en mi brazo, que no le tendría
                                           yo para matar una pulga \np{307}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\rp{punto}          {rodeos}               {Y venid al punto sin rodeos ni callejuelas, ni retazos ni añadiduras 
                                           \np{907}} \\ %☺ ☺
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------120
\specialrule{4pt}{0pt}{0pt}                  
\end{tabularx}                               
\end{center}                                 
\end{document}
```

I put 2 entries to 'toc', the words "prudencia" and "Pedro a Pedro". They appear in 'toc' but the link doesnot take to the page where they reside.

Comment: Please provide some codes you have so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the \addcontentsline Command see minmal example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Article}
\author{Yan}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Section I}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Column 1 Content}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    
    \hline
      Column 1 Content   & Column 2 \\
    \hline
      Column 3   & Column 4\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I made a clickable toc. if I put \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{key-word} there appears the page where the 'key-word' in a cell is placed, but, when I click it, takes me to the beginning of the table and not to the correct page.

Comment: Add the \phantomsection command to the page where you want the link to point.

Comment: I found that adding the command ```\phantomsection``` gives the desire result. For example:   ```desired_word\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{desired_word}```